# Changing the bsBDiagonal line width and gaps

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to produce a consistent interface in high DPI and standard DPI environments. We have a selection box that with paint using something like this:

```
theCanvas.Brush.style := bsBDiagonal;
theCanvas.pen.style := psClear;
theCanvas.brush.color := clBlue;
```

Is there any way to change the width of the lines and the gaps between the lines that are drawn by bsBDiagonal because these don't take into account the DPI of the monitor. A user with a high DPI system will see very fine diagonal lines that are very close together whereas a person with a regular DPI monitor will see painting that is further apart and wider.

For example. The one on the left is what a user on a regular DPI monitor will see and the one on the right is the high DPI equivalent.

[image: Hatching]

Comment: A custom brush bitmap perhaps.

Comment: @LURD I tried using a custom brush bitmap. There seems to be a problem with the transparency of the brush. At least I couldn't get it to work. Will post another question about that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatch brush always works in graphic device units. I met this problem with printers in old times and made this procedure:

```
//Fillstep depends linearly on DPI

procedure PrintHatchPolygon(Canvas: TCanvas; Pts: array of TPoint;
  FillStep: Integer);
var
  ClipRgn: HRGN;
  r: TRect;
  i, MaxSize, OldPenColor, HatchStyle: Integer;

  procedure Line(X1, Y1, X2, Y2: Integer);
  begin
    Canvas.MoveTo(X1, Y1);
    Canvas.LineTo(X2, Y2);
  end;

begin
  case Canvas.Brush.Style of
    bsVertical:
      HatchStyle := 1;
    bsHorizontal:
      HatchStyle := 2;
    bsFDiagonal:
      HatchStyle := 4;
    bsBDiagonal:
      HatchStyle := 8;
    bsCross:
      HatchStyle := 3;
    bsDiagCross:
      HatchStyle := 12;
  else
    HatchStyle := 0;
  end;
  OldPenColor := Canvas.Pen.Color;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := Canvas.Brush.Color;
  ClipRgn := CreatePolygonRgn(Pts, High(Pts) + 1, ALTERNATE);
  GetRgnBox(ClipRgn, r);
  MaxSize := r.Bottom - r.Top;
  if MaxSize < (r.Right - r.Left) then
    MaxSize := r.Right - r.Left;
  SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, ClipRgn);
  with r do begin
    if (HatchStyle and 1) > 0 then
      for i := 1 to (r.Right - r.Left) div FillStep do
        Line(Left + i * FillStep, Top, Left + i * FillStep, Bottom);
    if (HatchStyle and 2) > 0 then
      for i := 1 to (r.Bottom - r.Top) div FillStep do
        Line(Left, Top + i * FillStep, Right, Top + i * FillStep);

    //to equalize step
    //FillStep := 1414 * FillStep div 1000;

    if (HatchStyle and 4) > 0 then
      for i := 1 to 2 * MaxSize div FillStep do
        Line(Left, Bottom - i * FillStep, Left + i * FillStep, Bottom);
    if (HatchStyle and 8) > 0 then
      for i := 1 to 2 * MaxSize div FillStep do
        Line(Left, Top + i * FillStep, Left + i * FillStep, Top);
  end;
  SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0);
  DeleteObject(ClipRgn);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := OldPenColor;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: array [0 .. 2] of TPoint;
begin
  P[0] := Point(10, 10);
  P[1] := Point(100, 10);
  P[2] := Point(10, 200);
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;

  //value 8 for usual monitor dpi (72?)
  //value 60 for 600dpi printer
  PrintHatchPolygon(Canvas, P, 8);
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Polygon(P);
end;
```

Comment: My concern with this approach is that it would be slower than using a brush. I used some of your code to get a custom brush option going but could not get transparency working with it. It looks to me like this is the only way to go if you want transparency in the hatching.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a custom brush. I couldn't get the custom brush option working with transparency.

```
procedure SetupHatchBitmapBrush(ABitmap: TBitmap; const ABrushStyle:
    TBrushStyle; const AFillStep: Integer; const APenColor: TColor);
var
  bitmapSize: TSize;
  rect: TRect;
  cntr: Integer;
  maxSize: Integer;
  oldPenColor: Integer;
  hatchStyle: Integer;

  procedure Line(bBitmap: TBitmap; bX1, bY1, bX2, bY2: Integer);
  begin
    bBitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(bX1, bY1);
    bBitmap.Canvas.LineTo(bX2, bY2);
  end;

begin
  case ABrushStyle of
    bsVertical:   hatchStyle := 1;
    bsHorizontal: hatchStyle := 2;
    bsFDiagonal:  hatchStyle := 4;
    bsBDiagonal:  hatchStyle := 8;
    bsCross:      hatchStyle := 3;
    bsDiagCross:  hatchStyle := 12;
  else
    hatchStyle := 0;
  end;

  oldPenColor := ABitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color;
  try
    ABitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := APenColor;

    maxSize := ABitmap.Height;
    if maxSize < ABitmap.Width then
      maxSize := ABitmap.Width;
    if (hatchStyle and 1) > 0 then
      for cntr := 1 to ABitmap.Width div AFillStep do
        Line(ABitmap, cntr * AFillStep, 0, cntr * AFillStep, ABitmap.Height);
    if (hatchStyle and 2) > 0 then
      for cntr := 1 to ABitmap.Height div AFillStep do
        Line(ABitmap, 0, cntr * AFillStep, ABitmap.Width, cntr * AFillStep);

    if (hatchStyle and 4) > 0 then
      for cntr := 1 to 2 * maxSize div AFillStep do
        Line(ABitmap, 0, ABitmap.Height - cntr * AFillStep, cntr * AFillStep, ABitmap.Height);
    if (hatchStyle and 8) > 0 then
      for cntr := 1 to 2 * maxSize div AFillStep do
        Line(ABitmap, 0, cntr * AFillStep, cntr * AFillStep, 0);
  finally
    ABitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := oldPenColor;
  end;
end;

function CreatePatternBitmap(const ABrushStyle: TBrushStyle; const APenColor,
    ABackgroundColor: TColor; const AScaleFactor: Double): TBitmap;
const
  DEFAULT_SIZE = 8;
var
  bitmapStep: Integer;
begin
  bitmapStep := Trunc(DEFAULT_SIZE * AScaleFactor);
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Result.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Result.SetSize(bitmapStep * 2, bitmapStep * 2);

  SetupHatchBitmapBrush(Result, ABrushStyle, bitmapStep, APenColor);
end;
```

At some point we need to create the bitmap.

```
begin
  FBitmap := CreatePatternBitmap(bsBDiagonal, clRed, clWhite, 1.5);
end;
```

Painting would look like this:

```
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
  Canvas.Brush.style := bsBDiagonal;
  Canvas.Brush.Bitmap := FBitmap;
  Canvas.Rectangle(Rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
end;
```